# undefined in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, siebel

I have a problem from few days and i didn't find the solution...

I'm working on a SIEBEL App, and i would like to test a simple Jquery command.
So, i just launch the app on IE11, and try to write the command in web Console, the code :

```
$('div[id*="OC_Nom"]').click();
```

but IE returns  `"undefined". :/`

After I check it, the Jquery file is loaded by the app.

To confirm, I tried in Chrome and Firefox, and it's working.

I return to IE and test with a Javascript function:

```
document.getElementById("OC_Nom");
```

IE returns undefined again.

It's an SIEBEL app, so :

- HTML code is build by the app.
- There are some Jquery function in my
  applets, and works fine.
- Jquery and JS files are loaded and
  available in the console.

Comment: Can you check in IE that there is something with the id OC_Nom?  Could it be that IE generates a slightly different name?

Comment: OC_Nom is for the example, but the ID is correct in my code :)